# how to call a method in a GUI and display it's output?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I would like to display a method in a JOptionPane message...
for example.. a message shows up to the user and ask him to write
something, so when the user write that specific word, a method is called 
and the output of that method is shown as a message..

any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Whats your name?")
```

I hope you meant it